# Controller function not getting called on form submit

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, form-submit, request-mapping

I have created an form for submission and written a controller method to handle it in spring MVC. But the request is not reaching the controller method.Please let me know what mistake i'm making in writing the controller/form method.
Below is my code snippet which is self explanatory.

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/login/projectUpdate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateProjectStatus( User user,Model model,Authentication 
authentication,HttpServletRequest request,final RedirectAttributes 
redirectAttributes) {

    logger.debug("Update Project Status Data()");


    String projectname=request.getParameter("projectName");
    String projectStatus=request.getParameter("projectStatus");
    String projectStatusDate=request.getParameter("projectStatusDate");

    userService.updateProject(projectStatus,projectStatusDate,projectname);

    return "users/updateProject";

}
```

JSP form:

```
     <spring:url value="/users/login/projectUpdate" var="updateProjectUrl" />


     <form:form  method="post" modelAttribute="updateProjectForm" 
      action="${updateProjectUrl}" id="ProjectForm">




            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Projects</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:select path="project" multiple="false" class="form-control" id="project1">
                <form:option label="--Select--" value=""/>
                    <form:options items="${project}" />
                </form:select>
            </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:input path="projectDescription" type="text" class="form-control" id="projectDescription1" placeholder="Project Description" readonly="true"/>

            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:input path="projectStartDate" type="text"  class="form-control"   id="projectStartDate1" placeholder="Project Start Date" readonly="true" />

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Current Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:input path="projectCurrentStatus" type="text" class="form-control" id="projectCurrentStatus" placeholder="Project Status" readonly="true"/>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Current Status Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:input path="projectCurrentStatusDate" type="text"  class="form-control " id="projectCurrentStatusDate" placeholder="Project Current Status Date" readonly="true"/>

            </div>
        </div>




            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:select path="projectStatus" multiple="false" class="form-control" id="projectStatus1" >
                <form:option label="--Select--" value=""/>
                    <form:options items="${projectstatus}" />
                </form:select>
            </div>

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Status Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:input path="projectStatusDate" type="date"  class="form-control " id="projectStatusDate1" placeholder="Project Status Date" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd" />

            </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Team Members</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <form:input path="projectTeam" type="text" class="form-control " id="projectTeam1" placeholder="Project Team members" />

            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>       
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using BindingResult like below :

```
public String updateProjectStatus( User user,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model,Authentication authentication,HttpServletRequest request,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //check your errors here 
        }
}
```

and make sure all the fields which you are passing from JSP should be present in your User class.